# Draw a square using for loops in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle

def Draw_turtle(my_turtle):
    for i in range(1,5):

        my_turtle.turtle.forward(100)
        my_turtle.turtle.right(90)


        window = turtle.Screen()
        window.bgcolor('green')



        Alex = turtle.Turtle()
        Alex.color('black')
        Alex.speed(2)
        Alex.shape('triangle')

        Draw_turtle(Alex)
```

I know nothing of coding yet, when I run the above code nothing happens.  Can anyone help me, please.

Comment: Please fix your indentation to match exactly what you have, and format your code as code (highlight, ctrl + k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most of the right pieces and roughly in the right order.  We just need to fine tune your code a little bit as far as indentation, usage and style:

```
import turtle

def draw_square(my_turtle):

    for i in range(4):
        my_turtle.forward(100)
        my_turtle.right(90)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('green')

alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.color('black')
alex.speed('slow')
alex.shape('triangle')

draw_square(alex)

window.mainloop()
```